# BASS.NET encoder AAC to Icecast

Tags: vb.net, aac, bass

I'm developing with BASS.NET an AAC encoder to stream the output of my audio player directly to icecast.

No problems with the MP3 encoding and stream but AAC doesn't work. I'm using FAAC but trying other encoders the problem still the same.

Here's my portion of code

```
            Dim aac As New EncoderFAAC(G_REC)
            aac.InputFile = Nothing ' STDIN
            aac.OutputFile = Nothing ' STDOUT
            aac.FAAC_Bitrate = myStream(1).bitrate

            Debug.WriteLine("ENCODER AAC: " + aac.Start(Nothing, IntPtr.Zero, False))
            Stop
            Dim icy2 As New ICEcast(aac)
            icy2.ServerAddress = myStream(1).address
            icy2.ServerPort = myStream(1).port
            icy2.MountPoint = myStream(1).mountpoint
            icy2.Password = myStream(1).password
            icy2.PublicFlag = myStream(1).isPublic
            icy2.StreamDescription = myStream(1).streamDescr
            icy2.StreamGenre = myStream(1).streamGenre
            icy2.StreamName = myStream(1).streamName
            icy2.UpdateTitle(myStream(1).streamTitle, Nothing)

            ' use the BroadCast class to control streaming
            _broadcast2 = New BroadCast(icy2)
            _broadcast2.AutoReconnect = True
            _broadcast2.ReconnectTimeout = 10
            AddHandler _broadcast2.Notification, AddressOf OnBroadCast_Notification2
            _broadcast2.AutoConnect()
```

G_REC is defined like this:

```
    G_REC = Bass.BASS_RecordStart(48000, 2, BASSFlag.BASS_RECORD_PAUSE, 100, _myRecProc, IntPtr.Zero)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have the bass_aac extension installed?

Comment: yes, it start encoding but only for a bit of second than it stops.